# requiring an npm module using typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc, typescript1.8

I'm working on a new nodejs 5.10.1 project using typescript.

I have tsc installed version 1.8.9

I created a new project that contains the following configuration files:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "mdb-analyze",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "mdb-analyze.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "command-line-args": "^2.1.6"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": false
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

typings.json

```
{
  "name": "mdb-analyze",
  "version": false,
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

and this is my main mdb-analyze.ts file:

```
import * as commandLineArgs from 'command-line-args';

var cli = commandLineArgs([
  { name: 'verbose', alias: 'v', type: Boolean },
  { name: 'fjso', alias:'f',type: String, multiple: true, defaultOption: true },
  { name: 'help',alias:'h',type:Boolean }
])

var params = cli.parse();
if (params.help || !params.fjso || params.fjso.length == 0) {
    console.info(cli.getUsage());
} else {

}
```

when I try to compile with tsc i get the following error:

```
mdb-analyze.ts(5,34): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'command-line-args'.
```

welp i've been told to use typings to load typescript definitions for the modules i want. but searching on typings doesn't show this module. i'm new to typescript, and very confused on what to do next.

any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are no typings available you can write your own d.ts files containing necessary type declarations.

There are some samples for you: [link](https://github.com/Polymer/polytool/blob/master/custom_typings/command-line-args.d.ts), [link](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/blob/master/typings/command-line-args.d.ts)

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you. where do i place the d.ts file after creating it? what's the flow ?

Comment: I am used to create a root folder named `manual_typings` and put all my custom d.ts files in there. No extra steps required.

Comment: where can i find information on how to create custom d.ts files ?